# Testing multiple flags python

Tags: python

```
x = [1,2,3]
y = [1]
z = [0, 1, False]

if 1 in (x, y, z):
    print('passed')
```

Why does this code not print passed? Since 1 is in each of them shouldn't it print passed? When I put only one of the variables it does print passed though.

Comment: You're not checking if 1 is in each of them. You're checking if 1 is equal to x, y or z. That's what `in (x, y, z)` means.

Comment: @khelwood thank you! but when i do if 1 in x it also prints passed, why would that be?

Comment: `x` contains three ints, one of which is 1, so `1 in x` is true. `(x,y,z)` contains three lists, not ints, so `1 in (x,y,z)` is false.

Comment: Oh I think I get it now. if 1 in . . . will check each item, so in the case I put ```(x,y,z)``` it checks each list but for the y variable even though it has 1, it is seen as ```[1]``` which is not exactly ```1```.. But it does pass the flag if only one variable is listed at a time because it checks each item in the list? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your code is checking whether `1` is equal to `x` or `y` or `z` (which it is not, since they are all lists and `1` is a number). What you want to do instead is check if `1` is in [*all*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=ord#all) of the lists:

```
x = [1,2,3]
y = [1]
z = [0, 1, False]
if all(1 in l for l in (x, y, z)):
    print('passed')
```

Output:

```
passed
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if 1 is in each of them then you can do

```py
if 1 in x and 1 in y and 1 in z:
    print('passed')
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code,

```
if 1 in (x, y, z):
```

checks 1 in ([1, 2, 3], [1], [0,1,False])
In the condition its like  ( [list1], [list2], [list3] )
So its checking,  is list1,  list2 or list3 is equal to 1 or not!

So the full condition is look like this:

```
[1, 2, 3] = 1 # False

[1] = 1 # False

[0, 1, False] = 1 #False
```

As you can see everything is false,  during the if statement.

Use this simple syntex instead :

```
if (1 in x) or (1 in y) or (1 in z):
     print ("passed...")
```